# C#: CommandLineParser, how to pass an array of strings?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-arguments

I'm using [CommandLineParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser/) and I want to pass multiple arguments which should end up in a single array. Here's my class:

```
public class ClientConfig : Config
{

    [Option("load")]
    public string[]? Load { get; set; }

}
```

When I use the following command line:

```
my.exe --load=1 --load=2 --load=3
```

When parsed my "Load" property should be the following: `["1", "2", "3"]`. However when I try this I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try using the [Separator Property from the wiki](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/wiki/Getting-Started#option-attribute)?

Comment: @Andrew No, I'll try that but strictly speaking that doesn't answer the question

Comment: That's why I didn't post it as an answer and just asked if you had tried it yet. If you get the answer from the docs, feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the docs it uses `IEnumerable` for array of string so by this ClientConfig:

```cs
 public class ClientConfig
    {
        [Option("load")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Load { get; set; }

    }
```

this worked for me:

```
my.exe --load 1 2 3
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work, the parser outputs "  Option 'load:0' is unknown.
  Option 'load:1' is unknown.
  Option 'load:2' is unknown."

Comment: let me check it again

Answer (score 0):

The decorator should be OptionList!

```
public class ClientConfig
{
   [OptionList("load")]
   public IEnumerable<string> Load { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it like this:
`my.exe --load 1 2 3`

When it was `Option` I was getting null arguments but with `OptionList` it worked.
Hope it helps